# Can any body tell whats wrong with this code (New to python:()

Tags: python

Just wanted to print red and blue colors -

```
class color:
    def __init__(self,r,b):
        self.r = r
        self.b = b

        def displaycolor(self):
            print "The first should be :" self.r
            print "The 2nd should be :" self.b
pagal=color("Red","blue")
pagal.displaycolor()
```

Comment: Your indentation is broken `displaycolor` is defined within `init`.

Comment: welcome to SO - next time you want to ask a question, please try to give it a useful title that relates to the specific problem you are having, as it will help more people who can answer it to find your question and you will be more likely to get help. Also, if you are having problems with a bit of code, posting the code is a good start but you should also say what you wanted to happen and what actually happened instead, *including any specific error messages*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues: identation and string concatenation when printing:

```
class color:
    def __init__(self,r,b):
        self.r = r
        self.b = b

    def displaycolor(self):
        print "The first should be :", self.r
        print "The 2nd should be :", self.b
pagal=color("Red","blue")
pagal.displaycolor()
```

Comment: OMG, thanks a lot jabaldonedo

Comment: @muhammadnaveed If this answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it. It awards you and the person who helped you some rep points - this is SO's way of saying "thank you" :-)